# How to apply the different Domain Name into one IP and set the default path on apache

Tags: apache, dns, ip, cname

I have a domain name: abc.net mapping to 11.11.11.11 and it works fine
and my domain name is registry from www.asiaregistry.com
I also use the AWS EC2 for my service

Q1 : how to set www.abc.net or aaa.abc.net to work with DNS for internet user access?

Q2 : after done Q1 set, could it possible set the default path to my apache server as below?or it need other server for each ip to handle?

1. aaa.abc.net to 11.11.11.11/mobile
2. www.abc.net to 11.11.11.11/PC
3. bbb.abc.net to 11.11.11.11/mgmt

thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

What is your real domain?  This can help me answer your question more effectively.

You will need to configure name servers for your zone, your registrar probably offers a set of authoritative name servers so you need to put at least one NS record in your zone.

Once you have a name server in 'abc.net' you can add an A record for www.abc.net (your registry probably offers a way to edit the zone).

If you have an A record in place for www.abc.net then it makes sense to insert a CNAME record for each of the others that you would like to send to the same IP address.  A CNAME simply says that the answer for a hostname is a canonical name rather than a real IP address.